# How to see java annotation source?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, annotations, playframework-2.0

How does one get to see the source code of the annotation processors / handlers ? 
I'm specifically trying to see source code of the `@With` annotation and similar ones for my play applications ..

IntelliJ / Eclipse answer would do.

Edit: Also, I see that I can see the source in the framework repository.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse. Sorry for missing that, have added to the question.